# Is the Facebook SDK Required with iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

Not a newbie when it comes to working with Facebook on iOS, but my first foray was with iOS 5 and an iPhone 3GS.  Using the Facebook SDK from Facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/) was the only way to go.

Fast-forward to iOS 7 (and actually iOS 6), and Apple provides SocialKit, Account SDK, etc., and there are plenty of tutorials on line to do things like:

```
if ([self userHasAccessToFacebook]) {

    ACAccountStore* accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc]init];

    ACAccountType*  facebookAccountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

    NSDictionary* options = @{ACFacebookAppIdKey:        FACEBOOK_APP_KEY,
                              ACFacebookPermissionsKey:  @[@"publish_stream"],
                              ACFacebookAudienceKey:     ACFacebookAudienceEveryone};

    [accountStore
     requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType
     options:options
     completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
       if (granted) {
```

This worked if I had already authorized my Facebook application elsewhere (in this case I had gone through the login dialog on an Android device), but after revoking access (to test of course), I am getting

> message = "Error validating access token: Session does not match
>   current stored session. This may be because the user changed the
>   password since the time the session was created or Facebook has
>   changed the session for security reasons.";

when I try to share to Facebook.  This is even *after* the `requestAccessToAccountsWithType` indicates that access was granted.

I am assuming at this point I need to login and reauthorize my application, but none of the tutorials I've seen thus far given any indication as to how to do that.

At the end of the day the question is two-fold:  do I need to use the Facebook SDK from Facebook to perform all of the actions I am needing to perform, and if I don't, how does one get the app reauthorized using only SocialKit?

Comment: If all you want to do is post to the users timeline and you don't need to support below iOS6 then you don't need the SDK. With regard to the failed access, this is now controlled from the Settings app, so if you are getting errors, you need to tell your users that they need to allow access from there (I think!)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can integrate with Facebook without using the sdk, as long as the user is already logged-in in the settings of iOS,
Otherwise you will get an error as result

The object you should use is SLComposer. 
(You can find many examples and tutorials via web).

If it satisfies you, it's ok, but I suggest using the Facebook sdk, for using the native Facebook  application, that's how you won't lose those who didn't logged in with their Facebook account via iOS settings. 
You will be able to try and using the native app integration.

Don't hesitate to ask for further help.